# Error when trying to play audio: 998: Failure to setup sound, err = -50

Tags: ios, swift, audiotoolbox

I'm trying to play a sound when two objects collide and I get this error every time. I'm testing using my iPhone 6. Here's the code:

```
    guard soundEffects[sound] == nil else
    {
        print("Sound effect \(sound) already exists")
        return false
    }

    guard let soundURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(sound, withExtension:format, subdirectory:path) else
    {
        print("Error creating URL for resource \(sound)")
        return false
    }

    print(soundURL)

    var systemID : SystemSoundID = id

    soundEffects[sound] = systemID
    print(AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &systemID))

    id += 1
```

and I attempt to play it like so:

```
    guard soundEffects[sound] != nil else
    {
        print("Sound effect '\(sound)' not found")
        return false
    }

    print(soundEffects[sound]!)

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundEffects[sound]!)
```

The format of the file is wav and I printed out the code of the create method which was 0. I also can't seem to find any documentation on the error on apples website or anywhere else on the web. Am I doing something wrong?

Update:

Apparently storing the value in a dictionary and loading it later is what's causing the error to appear. But the thing is I need to have a dictionary of the ID's. How am I supposed to store the ID and why does storing it cause the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem by doing this:

```
let systemID : SystemSoundID = someUInt32
soundEffects[sound] = systemID
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &soundEffects[sound]!)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundEffects[sound]!)
```

It seems that the object that the create method performs its actions on is the only object you can call play on, therefore you need to perform the create method specifically on the instance of the dictionary (or whatever object you're trying to store the sound in).